# curl vulnerabilities reported against a container image that runs a dotnetcore process

Tags: docker, security, pci-dss, snyk

We're running a dotnetcore web application on a Debian 11.7-slim image in AWS ECS+Fargate.  Snyk Container is reporting that `curl` 7.74 is present on the image and suffers from "CVE-2023-23914 - cleartext transmission of sensitive information".

We have run `apt update/upgrade` in the image, and I can only assume that due to package constraints, curl cannot be updated to 8.x.

Our process does not use curl.  Is this mitigation against the reported vulnerability - especially from PCI-DSS point of view?

Comment: I believe an answer to this would be an opinion based on your individual threat scenario. Some may be defending against attackers that can start the container with a different configuration, changing the entrypoint.

Comment: Not sure I get your point, or perhaps I wasn't clear - my question was regarding a running container that has already started: only the entrypoint process is actually executing.

Comment: I was trying to write a general purpose question that would address how static image vulnerability analysis relates to a running container..  If I was running a virtual machine with a webserver that had a vulnerability listed against a file editor, I feel that the website is not vulnerable

Comment: The web server may not be vulnerable, but the environment where the webserver is running contains vulnerable applications or libraries. You're probably looking for a VEX report, but I believe many disagree with how you would assess the image and create that VEX.

Comment: I've re-submitted my question with specifics rather than generalities - but I think the essence of the question has been lost.

Comment: 7.88 is available in stable (bookworm/1.12) and bullseye backports: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/curl

Comment: Snyk doesn't scan for runtime, so it doesn't know whether a vuln lib is being called or not (by your app or anything else sitting on the system). And one also needs to be sure that that lib isn't called, directly or by any subprocess. It means, if you go with dynamic or runtime scanning, you need to be sure you have 100% test coverage.